# How to edit this very complicated Joomla query that kills the server

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have to edit the query bellow on a Joomla site. This query is so slow and hard and it very often kills the server and I get errors Gateway timeout.. Please help me to edit it if possible to avoid so many Left Joins because I think the make it so "heavy".. The query is:

```
SELECT 
o.*, o.price AS value, c.name AS catname, g.title AS groupname, u.name AS editor, 
u.id AS userid, u.block as blockuser, t.name as typename, t.id as typeid, 
a.name as agentname, a.id as agentid, image.path as imagepath, 
image.fname as imagefilename, image.type as imagetype, l.title AS language_title,
l.image AS langImage, u.name AS editor     
FROM (mytable_estateagent AS o, mytable_estateagent_categories AS c ) 
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT * FROM mytable_estateagent_images AS img 
        WHERE 1 AND (img.type = '.jpg' OR img.type = '.gif' OR img.type = '.png') 
        AND ( img.ordering= 1 or img.ordering= 0 ) AND img.published = 1 
        GROUP BY img.objid 
    ) 
as image ON (image.objid = o.id)    
LEFT JOIN mytable_estateagent_type AS t ON (o.type = t.id)        
LEFT JOIN mytable_languages AS l ON l.lang_code = o.language     
LEFT JOIN mytable_estateagent_agents AS a ON (o.agent = a.id) 
LEFT JOIN mytable_viewlevels AS g ON (g.id = o.access) 
LEFT JOIN mytable_users AS u ON (u.id = o.created_by) 
LEFT JOIN mytable_users AS uc ON uc.id = o.checked_out 
WHERE 1 AND (c.id = o.cat) ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: Besides the query, you can improve the query's speed by setting good indexes

Comment: Michael, any concrete suggestions?

Comment: It will help to index the columns in your ON statements (like o.checked_out, o.created_by, ...)

Comment: Michael, this didn't help, still slow, any other suggestions please?

Comment: I'd need to see your tables structures, coulumn types and so on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63691/discussion-between-europeuser-and-michael).

Comment: Also, as a start, rewrite your query without 'SELECT *'. Instead name and properly qualify the columns you want returned. This helps us too.

Comment: Note that you select no columns from the outer joined table instance `uc`, so you can remove that join without affecting the query result.

Answer (score 0):

See comments above, but note also that this bit (edited)...

```
SELECT o.*
...    
LEFT JOIN
 (  SELECT DISTINCT img.objid 
       FROM mytable_estateagent_images img 
      WHERE img.type IN('.jpg','.gif','.png') 
        AND img.ordering IN(1,0) 
        AND img.published = 1
 ) image 
ON image.objid = o.id
```

... can be (further) rewritten as follows...

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.*
... 
LEFT 
JOIN mytable_estateagent_images image
  ON image.objid
 AND image.type IN('.jpg','.gif','.png') 
 AND image.ordering IN(1,0) 
 AND image.published = 1
...
```

Comment: Strawberry,sorry for the delay, I was away, thanks for the suggestions, image.type IN('.jpg','.gif','.png') saved some seconds, dont't you think instead of AND image.ordering IN(1,0) that AND image.ordering < 2 is faster? But still query takes alot of time - 23 seconds..

Comment: "Note that you select no columns from the outer joined table instance uc, so you can remove that join without affecting the query result" what you mean with this?

Comment: This bit "LEFT JOIN mytable_users AS uc ON uc.id = o.checked_out" is redundant - and switching from OR to IN wasn't the important bit. The important bit was removing the subquery!